# Mhchem in mathjax-node does not render complex formulas correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjax

I use mathjax-node with mhchem to render chemical equations. The problem is tex expressions beyond simple formulas (e.g. with text over arrows or with text subscripts) do not render correctly — though they render OK in test drive on [mhchem github](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).

For example, here are the results for:

```
\ce{H2O2 ->[MnO2] H2O + O2}
```

[image: As you can see, index in the formula above arrow is not subscripted.]
The index in the formula above arrow is not subscripted.

Or, for:

```
\ce{KI + H2SO4_{{(conc.)}} -> I2 + SO2 + K2SO4 + H2O}
```

[image: The dot is not escaped, but gets changed for \cdot.]
The dot is not escaped, but gets changed for \cdot.

Escaping the dot by using \text{} does not work at all — it just gets messed up:

```
\ce{KI + H2SO4_{\text{(conc.)}} -> I2 + SO2 + K2SO4 + H2O}
```

[image]

Is there anything to do to overcome these problems? The only package not up to date is Mathjax, but its version is determined by Mathjax-node.

```
Node version: 12.22.2
Mathjax version: 2.7.9
Mathjax-node version: 2.1.1
Mhchem version: 3.3.2
```